# Ошибка java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

Чем данная ошибка может быть вызвана и как ее вообще можно решить?

```
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate javax/transaction/xa/XAException which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/jdbc/MysqlXAException.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/io/TlsEncryptingByteChannel.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/Mysqlx$ClientMessages$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/Mysqlx$ClientMessages$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/Mysqlx$ClientMessages.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/Mysqlx$Error$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/Mysqlx$Error$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/Mysqlx$Error.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/Mysqlx$Ok$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/Mysqlx$Ok$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/Mysqlx$Ok.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/Mysqlx$ServerMessages$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/Mysqlx$ServerMessages$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/Mysqlx$ServerMessages.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxConnection$Capabilities$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxConnection$Capabilities$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxConnection$Capabilities.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxConnection$CapabilitiesGet$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxConnection$CapabilitiesGet$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxConnection$CapabilitiesGet.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxConnection$CapabilitiesSet$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxConnection$CapabilitiesSet$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxConnection$CapabilitiesSet.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxConnection$Capability$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxConnection$Capability$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxConnection$Capability.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxConnection$Close$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxConnection$Close$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxConnection$Close.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Delete$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Delete.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Find$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Find$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Insert$TypedRow$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Insert$TypedRow$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Insert$TypedRow.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Insert.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Limit$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Limit$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Limit.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Order$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Order$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Order.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Projection$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Projection$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Projection.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Update$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Update$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$Update.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$UpdateOperation$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$UpdateOperation$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxCrud$UpdateOperation.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Any$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Any$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Any.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Array$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Array$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Array.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Object$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Object$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Object$ObjectField$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Object$ObjectField$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Object$ObjectField.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Object.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Scalar$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Scalar$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Scalar$Octets$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Scalar$Octets$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Scalar$Octets.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Scalar$String$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Scalar$String$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Scalar$String.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxDatatypes$Scalar.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpect$Close$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpect$Close$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpect$Close.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpect$Open$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpect$Open$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpect$Open$Condition$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpect$Open$Condition$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpect$Open$Condition.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpect$Open.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$Array$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$Array$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$Array.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$ColumnIdentifier$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$ColumnIdentifier$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$ColumnIdentifier.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$DocumentPathItem$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$DocumentPathItem$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$DocumentPathItem.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$Expr$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$Expr$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$Expr.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$FunctionCall$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$FunctionCall$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$FunctionCall.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$Identifier$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$Identifier$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$Identifier.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$Object$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$Object$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$Object$ObjectField$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$Object$ObjectField$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$Object$ObjectField.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$Object.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$Operator$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$Operator$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxExpr$Operator.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxNotice$Frame$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxNotice$Frame$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxNotice$Frame.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxNotice$SessionStateChanged$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxNotice$SessionStateChanged$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxNotice$SessionStateChanged.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxNotice$SessionVariableChanged$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxNotice$SessionVariableChanged$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxNotice$SessionVariableChanged.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxNotice$Warning$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxNotice$Warning$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxNotice$Warning.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxResultset$ColumnMetaData$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxResultset$ColumnMetaData$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxResultset$ColumnMetaData.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxResultset$FetchDone$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxResultset$FetchDone$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxResultset$FetchDone.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxResultset$FetchDoneMoreOutParams$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxResultset$FetchDoneMoreOutParams$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxResultset$FetchDoneMoreOutParams.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxResultset$FetchDoneMoreResultsets$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxResultset$FetchDoneMoreResultsets$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxResultset$FetchDoneMoreResultsets.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxResultset$Row$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxResultset$Row$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxResultset$Row.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSession$AuthenticateContinue$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSession$AuthenticateContinue$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSession$AuthenticateContinue.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSession$AuthenticateOk$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSession$AuthenticateOk$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSession$AuthenticateOk.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSession$AuthenticateStart$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSession$AuthenticateStart$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSession$AuthenticateStart.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSession$Close$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSession$Close$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSession$Close.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSession$Reset$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSession$Reset$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSession$Reset.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSql$StmtExecute$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSql$StmtExecute$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSql$StmtExecute.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/AbstractParser which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSql$StmtExecuteOk$1.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$Builder which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSql$StmtExecuteOk$Builder.
IncrementalVisitor parseParents could not locate com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage which is an ancestor of project class com/mysql/cj/mysqlx/protobuf/MysqlxSql$StmtExecuteOk.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0ProxyConnection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0ProxyConnection

`ClassNotFoundException` означает, что где-то в коде делается попытка загрузить **по имени** класс `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0ProxyConnection`, но такой класс не обнаруживается. Возможная причина: не подключена нужная зависимость.